# Ember save needs headers. Doesnt seem to pass thru RESTAdapter headers function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to pass an Authorization token via header and that works fine for `find` and `findQuery` but `save` doesn't seem to invoke the header function?!

```
createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
   var data = {};
   var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

   var snapshot = record._createSnapshot();
   serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, snapshot, { includeId: true });

   return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, null, record), "POST", { data: data });
},
```

No call to header in the above RESTAdapter

I could quite easily add a header call but ... does seems odd that its missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, its simple enuff to override the createRecord.. seems a bit odd that it was missing in the RESTAdapter.

```
createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
   var data = {};
   var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

   var snapshot = record._createSnapshot();
   serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, snapshot, { includeId: true });

   var headers = this.headers(); // Add this

   return this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, null, record), "POST", { headers: headers, data: data }); 
 // And note the headers: data versus data only
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwriting store methods extend `RESTAdapter`

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: {
    'API_KEY': 'secret key',
    'ANOTHER_HEADER': 'Some header value'
  }
});
```

> Arbitrary headers can be set as key/value pairs on the RESTAdapter's headers property and Ember Data will send them along with each ajax request.

See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_custom-http-headers

Comment: placing a breakpoint in header suggests that "save doesn't [seem to] invoke the header function"